# Swift protocol as an init parameter called from Objective C class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, initialization, bridging-header

I have a swift protocol which i have defined for testing `openUrl` functionality in iOS. It looks something like this:

```
protocol URLOpener {

    func open(_ url: URL, options: [String : Any], completionHandler completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
    func canOpenURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool

}

extension UIApplication: URLOpener {}
```

Note that `UIApplication` is class is conformed to this protocol.

Now i have a class which takes an object `URLOpener` type to initilize that class

```
import Foundation
class GenericHandler : NSObject {

    required init(urlOpener: URLOpener) {
        super.init()
    }

    func aaa() {
        NBLog("aaaaa")
    }
}
```

I want to use this GenericHandler class from Objective C but i gives me an error that it could not find the initilizer.

```
  GenericHandler *handler = [[GenericHandler alloc] initWithUrlOpener:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
        [handler aaa];

 No visible @interface for 'GenericHandler' declares the selector 'initWithUrlOpener:'
```

However if i change the initizer so that it accepts `String` parameter then it starts to work fine.

```
import Foundation
class GenericHandler : NSObject {

    required init(urlOpener: String) {
        super.init()
    }

    func aaa() {
        NBLog("aaaaa")
    }

}



GenericHandler *handler = [[GenericHandler alloc] initWithUrlOpener:@"test"];
        [handler aaa];
```

This just works fine. Can anyone guide me whats the issue withURLOpener protocol or how i can make it working with URLOpener parameter.

Comment: try to expose the protocol into ObjC by adding `@objc protocol ...`

Comment: when i do that `Objective-C method openURL:options:completionHandler: provided by method open(_:options:completionHandler:) does not match the requirement's selector (open:options:completionHandler:) `

Comment: Play with `protocol` superclass, one of these should work: `protocol URLOpener: NSObjectProtocol`, `protocol URLOpener: NSObject`, `protocol URLOpener: class`

Comment: None of them works.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I just struggled with the same question.

You have to expose both the `protocol` and the `init` to Objective-C.

```
@objc protocol URLOpener {
    func open(_ url: URL, options: [String : Any], completionHandler completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
    func canOpenURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool
}

extension UIApplication: URLOpener {}
```

-

```
import Foundation

class GenericHandler : NSObject {

    @objc required init(urlOpener: URLOpener) {
        super.init()
    }

    func aaa() {
        NBLog("aaaaa")
    }
}
```

You can always check your generated header file to see if your Swift code is available in Objective-C. See the paragraph "Importing Swift into Objective-C"  [from the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122).